# Web-to-Case creates record bypassing Validation Rule

Tags: case, validation-rule, assignment-rules, web2case

**Scenario :** 
I am using Web-to-case to create case records.

I  have one Validation Rule which checks -

```
AND((Account.RecordType.DeveloperName = 'XYZ'),(RecordType.DeveloperName = 'ABC'))
```

But here is the interesting part -- 
**Cases are getting created** - who has RecordType.DeveloperName=ABC & Account.RecordType.DeveloperName=XYZ.

So, *I think* this is happening because of Order of execution -

Validation Rule --then --assignment rule

May be my Account record is getting assigned to Case after Validation Rule execution that is the reason Validation Rule is failing in 2nd condition --- and allowing to create Case.

**Question:**

1) What are all the possible ways to stop "Web-to-Case" from creating such a Case record.

2) Am I missing something ?

3) Any suggestions / help / corrections ?

Comment: You can't reference RecordType.Name in validation rule... You need to use global variable....$RecordType.Name

Comment: Thank you buddy, But I mentioned to Forgot the syntax @PrabhatKumar bro ..... My validation rule is right. Concentrate on Issue ..... Updated Question :)

Comment: Account and Contact aren't assigned until after validation rules, as you expect. This means that the system can't run those validations on the account, because validation occurs before the account is assigned. You could probably use an after-insert database trigger to check the account's record type, because it should be available then. You can still use addError on a record in an after-insert trigger to prevent it from being created. Let me know if this works.

Comment: Oki, Thanks @sfdcfox; I wasn't sure about Trigger - I hope record will not get created at all !  ---- But After-Insert trigger means our record is already created right ?

Comment: During the after insert trigger, the record has not yet been persisted to the database. Try it out and let me know if that works.